# Apache-Drill - different results for JDBC query in embedded and distributed mode

Tags: jdbc, apache-drill, apache-zookeeper

I connected to Drill in Embedded mode(without zookeeper) using the following URL **jdbc:drill:drillbit=local** . Then I connected using the distributed mode(with zookeeper and drillbit) using the following URL **jdbc:drill:zk=local**. The "show schemas" and "show tables" command give different results in both the cases even though the environment is same. Why is it happening and how to get the same results for both the cases?

Answer (score 0):

by default Drill uses a different path to save all the storage plugin configurations when running in embedded mode (in general it's /tmp/drill/) vs in distributed mode (it's saved in Zookeeper).
So if you made some changes to your workspace while running in embedded mode it won't show up when you run in distributed mode and vice versa.